# Связь многие-ко-многим в рамках одной модели: друзья и подписчики

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Ситуация такая: есть таблица `friendships`, куда заносятся связи между пользователями. Поля `user_id` и `friend_id`. Текущий юзер (`current_user`) может заносится в таблицу и как `user_id` и `friend_id`, все зависит от того, я добавил пользователя в друзья или он меня. Т.е, если я его добавляю в друзья, то связь условно выглядит так:

```
user_id = current_user, friend_id = another_user
```

если он меня добавит, то тогда:

```
user_id = another_user, friend_id = current_user
```

Если в таблице под `user_id = current_user`, то удаление друзей проходит без проблем, но как только мы сталкиваемся с удалением связи вида `user_id = another_user, friend_id = current_user` - ничего не выходит.

Вот как я пробовал решить проблему в контроллере: `friendships_controller.rb`:

```
def remove_from_friend
  if friend = current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(params[:id])
    friend.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    friend = current_user.friendships.find_by_user_id(params[:id])
    friend.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Модель `user.rb`:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,     :confirmable


has_many :posts, foreign_key: :user_id
has_many :recipient_posts, class_name: 'Post', foreign_key: :recipient_id
has_many :comments
has_many :messages
has_many :recipient_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :recipient_id

has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, presence: true

has_many :feeds
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

acts_as_liker
```

модель `friendship.rb` :

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :friend_id


scope :friends, ->(user_id) do
user_requests_ids = Friendship.select(:friend_id).where('user_id = ?  AND status="accepted"', user_id).to_sql
friend_requests_ids = Friendship.select(:user_id).where('friend_id = ? AND status="accepted"', user_id).to_sql

User.where("users.id IN (#{user_requests_ids}) OR users.id IN (#{friend_requests_ids})")
end


scope :requests, ->(user_id)do
requests_friend = Friendship.select(:user_id).where('friend_id = ? AND status="request"', user_id).to_sql

User.where("users.id IN (#{requests_friend})")
end
```

Comment: Алгоритм (а) однозначно ошибочный, может выбрать запись неверно, (б) не DRY, обе ветки кончаются одинаково. Приложите определение `friendships` из `User`.

Comment: Ошибка-то какая? Из заголовка и упоминания о том, что `ничего не выходит`, не очень понятно. Хотя догадываюсь, что там в `friend` оказывается `nil`. Предлагаю начать с анализа запроса, заодно внимательно посмотреть на форму и понять что приходит в качестве `id`.

Comment: Если не сложно покажите модели Friendship и User

Comment: внес в вопрос модели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно организовать две has_many-связи: друзья `friends` (она у вас уже есть) и подписчики `subscribers` - ее у вас пока нет. Тогда вы сможете в любой момент удалять либо друзей, либо подписчиков, не конструируя сложные условия в вашем коде. Для того, чтобы организовать связь многие ко многим через промежуточную таблицу `friendships`, которая бы работала в обе стороны, вам не достаточно одной промежуточной ассоциации.

Для этого вам придется построить две промежуточные связи `friendships_to` и `friendships_from`, которые потом задействовать уже в конечных `has_many` ассоциациях. Ниже приводится приводится пример модели `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships_to,
           foreign_key: 'user_id',
           class_name: 'Friendship',
           dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friendships_from,
           foreign_key: 'friend_id',
           class_name: 'Friendship',
           dependent: :destroy

  has_many :friends, through: :friendships_to, source: :friend
  has_many :subscribers, through: :friendships_from, source: :user
end
```

Модель `Friendship` остается без изменений. Так вы получаете возможность извлекать друзей (на кого вы подписались) и подписчиков (кто подписался на вас) и работать с ними обычными средствами ActiveRecord - искать, фильтровать, удалять.

```
usr = User.find_by(name: 'User1')
# Друзья
usr.frinds
# Подписчики 
usr.subscribers
```